# How do you export an Excel file to CSV with rows have differing number of columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, csv

I have text file with a header, master, detail, footer record.  The types of rows all have a different amount of columns.   When I export to CSV, it exports all data and puts in fillers to the longest row with the number of columns.  Is there a setting to stop this from happening?

ie. Header - 6 columns; master - 10 columns; detail - 15 columns; footer - 2 columns;
when export, all rows have 15 columns so getting a lot of commas at the end of a row...

Thanks!

Comment: It does this so if you imported that file, the rows would keep columns aligned.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want the CSV file "jagged"? I have encountered this situation before, but lived with the limitation of Excel reading and producing a "square" structure. We simply looked at the columns we wanted in each section and ignored the remainder.

Answer (score 0):

when you export a file it is normal that it uses the row with longest column
txt,,txt,txt,,,,,
txt,txt,txt,txt,txt,,,
,,,,,,,,
if it wouldn´t operate that way, it will open the file with errors the next time you open it

if you do not want the empty places you can open it with an text editor eg. notepad++ and search replace the ,,  with a space